# Decompressing file with gzip produces file with no read-permissions on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, gzip

I am attempting to decompress a .gz file using the GnuWin32 gzip program in Windows 7. I have full permissions on the compressed file, and my user account is an administrator. However, I end up not having read permissions on the decompressed file. To get read permissions I would have to manually change the permissions on it through right-clicking and selecting Properties > Security. I am able to do this exact same thing with no permission problems in Windows XP, which leads me to believe that Windows 7's user account control system is causing problems. Does anyone know what I can do to make things work as I would expect (read permission on the decompressed file) in Windows 7?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is there some reason you need to use GnuWin32? I highly recommend [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/), even more than WinRAR. It's free, and I use it for everything, even ISOs. There's hardly anything it won't archive or decompress properly. I generally use the .tar.gz format with it :)

One note, if you're on x64, use the x64 version. Some people have been known to experience bugginess using the x86 on x64 Windows.

I'll assume this is an answer since I know for a fact it will deal with your permissions issues, and since you didn't specify any reason why you needed to use the other app. Cheers! :)